# search for two identical characters and filter them on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

how this task can be carried out is more optimized.
Various data come to me.
Example data : test/123, test , test/, test/123/
and I need to write the correct data to my database, but first I need to find it. The correct ones will be in the  `test/123/`  format

and then divide them into variables
a = test
b = 123

Tell me how it can be done ?

the data can be of any size

Comment: Is "test/123 format/" correct?

Comment: It's really unclear what the question actually is. Could you provide some input data and expected output?

Comment: sorry, the correct format
is 
test/123/ @wizzwizz4

Comment: input:
test
test/
test/123
test/123/

The correct ones will be if I get test/123/ @BRemmelzwaal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers for a data set of one or more letters ("test" in the example above) and one or more digits ("123" in the example above)

```py
import re

data = 'test/123/'
m = re.match(r'(\w+)/(\d+)/', data)

if m:
    a = m[1]
    b = m[2]
    print(f'Found a = {a}, b = {b}')
else:
    print('no match')
```

For more tweaks of the pattern, refer e.g. to python's [Regular Expressions HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Comment: the data can be of any size

Comment: also, you do not have the correct data, they should be test/123/

Comment: the data can be of any size

Comment: @user20881617 what do you mean?

Comment: the data can be of any size, Name/123123/ Clinet/456/
forwar/123123123/ how to process it if you have a fixed size?